# Which one is greater: $\log_{13}160$ or $\log_{17}291$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, number-comparison

Which one is greater: $\log_{13}160$ or $\log_{17}291$?

Comparing logarithms with equal bases is fairly easy. Here they aren't equal, though. In similar problems I have seen that we can compare each of the logarithms with zero or $1$, but here neither of them works, e.g $$\log_{13}160>1=\log_{13}13\\\log_{17}291>1=\log_{17}17$$ What else can we do? P. P. I am not very fluent with functions.

Comment: Do you want to do this without a calculator ?

Comment: @Peter, yes, of course.

Comment: **Hint**: Notice that $160$ is close to $13^2$ (but slightly smaller). Notice that $291$ is near $17^2$ (but a little bigger).

Comment: In this particular case, you can easily compare them (see the hint) , but in general this is messy. The closer the values are , the more difficult it is usually to compare them.

Comment: @Peter How messy?

Comment: @StinkingBishop, thank you! Is this like a general method? Can we use it for comparing e.g. $$\log_{\frac13}26^{-1},log_{\frac15}\frac{1}{126}?$$

Comment: @Medi Not particularly general, but you see that this other problem also has the figures cooked in a similar way. $5^3=125\approx 126$ and $3^3=27\approx 26$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log_{17}291 > \log_{17}289 = 2$$
$$\log_{17}291 > 2$$
$$\log_{13}160 < \log_{13}169 = 2$$
$$\log_{13}160 < 2$$

Thus:
$$\log_{13}160 < 2 < \log_{17}291$$
$$\log_{13}160 < \log_{17}291$$

Comment: Formatting tip:  type `$\log x$` to obtain $\log x$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: OK.

Comment: Thank you!  Can we use this method for comparing e.g. $$\log_{\frac13}26^{-1},log_{\frac15}\frac{1}{126}?$$

Comment: @Medi: Sure. 1) Think of relation between $\log_{1/3}x$and $\log_{3}x$. 2) Notice that $26 < 27 = 3^3$ and $126 > 125 = 5^3$.

Comment: @mentallurg, I'm still not sure how to operate. $$\log_\frac1326^{-1}=-\log_326^{-1}$$ What next?

Comment: Now remember that $\log_a x^{-1} = -\log_a x$.